# Numpy Memory Error after appending 15K+ images

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, deep-learning, numpy-ndarray

I 'm creating Deep Learning Model for Convolution Neural Network.

I have 90,000 images each for vary size.

I Resize them to fixed Size(512,512) and append them to numpy array.
However I exceed the memory limit resulting into Memory Error.
I came Across Sparse matrix as a way but I can't figure out how to do so.

Please Guide me yours Sincerely,
Vidit Shah

Comment: PyTorch has an entire class called DataLoader dedicated to loading data one batch at a time to overcome memory limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have them all in memory at the same time? If you are running a deep learning model, you are almost certainly using stochastic gradient descent which means you are only using a fraction of your dataset at any given iteration. Only load the data you need at the current iteration. You can easily do this with generators, for example:

```
def data_generator():
    while True:
        for image in images:
            yield read(image)
```